# Load 3 user controls (web application) on their own threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, user-controls

I have 3 user controls that pull data from the database and display a gridview.  I need all of these 3 gridviews to run at the same time.

How can I use threading to accomplish this?

I forgot to mention it is being developed in C#

Also, trying to create a thread in the page that is calling the 3 user controls is shutting down my localhost webserver whenever the thread is hit.

What is causing this?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: We are writting it in C#

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, hopefully I can still be helpful:

You probably want to look into ASP.NET async pages.  There's a great writeup on MSDN Magazine: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx

Almost half way down the page there's a header "Asynchronous Data Binding" that I believe addresses your issue.